# Position of all words in string

Tags: python, string, integer, position

I need to take in a sentence. Find all the words within that sentence. Then find the position of every word in the sentence. Then make a **.txt** document with all the words and their position in, for example.

```
Sentence=some people dont like coding but some people do like coding.
Words=some people dont like coding but do
Position = 1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,6,4,5
```

But the words and numbers need to outputted in a document.

Any ideas?

**Update**: I now have this.

```
sentence= input("Enter a sentence")
words=sentence.split (" ")
 for (i, subword) in enumerate(words):
    print (i+1)
```

But if the word is repeated it treats it as the same word.

Comment: There are lots of ideas. Have you tried researching any of them on your own? The [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/index.html), for example, tells you how to do a lot of what you're looking for, either directly or by providing building blocks.

Comment: Thanks I'll look there

Answer (score 0):

You must keep unique words with their rank in an container. If performance is a concern, you could use an `OrderedDict` in the `collections` module, or simply a dict and sort it at the end according with the value (key would be the word, value the rank).

Then you iterate the initial list, looking whether the word in in the unique word container or not. If it is not, add it to the container, then in any case store the rank to position list.

Here is a simple implementation using a list as unique word container (a list automatically gives the rank with `index` method):

```
words = sentence.split(" ")
uniqwords = []
position = []
for word in words:
    if word in uniqwords:
        position.append(uniqwords.index(word) + 1)
    else:
        uniqwords.append(word)
        position.append(len(uniqwords)) # index of a newly appended elt is len - 1 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I will show you some example code that may help you. And you also need to do some preproccess of your sentence, such as split your sentence by ',', '.', ':' and so on.
The simple code is follow:

```
Sentence='some people dont like coding but some people do like coding'
sentList = Sentence.split(' ')
position = [word.index(x)+1 for x in sentList]
```

The results is like this:

```
In [18]: print(position)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 7, 4, 5]
```

I hope it can help you.

Comment: [word.index(x)+1 for x in sentList]     this code has much higher performance than for loop.